# cancan + rspec = uninitialized constant Anonymou (no s)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cancan

### Important update

I have the following line in my application_controller:

```
authorize_resource if: :html_auth
```

Removing it everything seems to work. Is there a way to call `authorize_resources` for all my controllers without breaking the tests?

### Original question

I'm testing my application controller with RSpec using an anonymous controller (which I'm not sure is the standard practice, but this is what Google led me to).

This is the full RSpec with only one test, that is failing:

```
require "spec_helper"


shared_examples_for "normal errors for html format" do |action, expected_error|
  it "raises the error" do
    expect { get action}.to raise_error(expected_error)
  end
end

describe ApplicationController do
  controller do
    def runtime_error
      raise RuntimeError
    end

    def handable_json_error
      raise ApplicationController::InvalidParams, "model"
    end
  end

  before do
    @routes.draw do
      get 'anonymous/runtime_error'
      get 'anonymous/handable_json_error'
    end
  end

  describe "#handle_exceptions" do
    context "when runtime error happens" do
      describe "with http format" do
        it_behaves_like "normal errors for html format", :runtime_error, RuntimeError
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And my spec helper:

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
require 'simplecov'
SimpleCov.start 'rails'

ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'

require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'
require 'authlogic/test_case'

include Authlogic::TestCase

Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods

  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = true

  config.order = "random"
end
```

I noticed that the backtrace didn't even hit my controller, so I don't know if is related.
The output of RSpec with `-b`, to get the full trace:

```
rspec -b spec/controllers/application_controller_spec.rb 
F

Failures:

  1) ApplicationController#handle_exceptions when runtime error happens with http format behaves like normal errors for html format raises the error
     Failure/Error: expect { get action}.to raise_error(expected_error)
       expected RuntimeError, got #<NameError: uninitialized constant Anonymou> with backtrace:
         # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:230:in `block in constantize'
         # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `each'
         # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `constantize'
         # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:54:in `constantize'
         # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/cancan-1.6.10/lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:147:in `resource_class'
         # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/cancan-1.6.10/lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:154:in `resource_class_with_parent'
         # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/cancan-1.6.10/lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:41:in `authorize_resource'
         # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/cancan-1.6.10/lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:10:in `block in add_before_filter'
         # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:429:in `_run__1066669752__process_action__49729610__callbacks'
         # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
         # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
         # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
         # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
         # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
         # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
         # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
         # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
         # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
         # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
         # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
         # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
         # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
         # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
         # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/testing.rb:17:in `process_with_new_base_test'
         # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:475:in `process'
         # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:49:in `process'
         # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:392:in `get'
         # ./spec/controllers/application_controller_spec.rb:6:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
         # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-expectations-2.13.0/lib/rspec/matchers/built_in/raise_error.rb:22:in `call'
         # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-expectations-2.13.0/lib/rspec/matchers/built_in/raise_error.rb:22:in `matches?'
         # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-expectations-2.13.0/lib/rspec/expectations/handler.rb:23:in `handle_matcher'
         # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-expectations-2.13.0/lib/rspec/expectations/expectation_target.rb:34:in `to'
         # ./spec/controllers/application_controller_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
         # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:114:in `instance_eval'
         # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:114:in `block in run'
         # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/extensions/instance_eval_with_args.rb:16:in `instance_exec'
         # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/extensions/instance_eval_with_args.rb:16:in `instance_eval_with_args'
         # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:247:in `instance_eval_with_args'
         # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:87:in `block (2 levels) in run'
         # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:89:in `call'
         # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:89:in `run'
         # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:418:in `run_hook'
         # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:329:in `run_around_each_hooks'
         # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:256:in `with_around_each_hooks'
         # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:111:in `run'
         # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:390:in `block in run_examples'
         # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:386:in `map'
         # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:386:in `run_examples'
         # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:371:in `run'
         # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:372:in `block in run'
         # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:372:in `map'
         # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:372:in `run'
         # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:372:in `block in run'
         # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:372:in `map'
         # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:372:in `run'
         # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:372:in `block in run'
         # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:372:in `map'
         # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:372:in `run'
         # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:372:in `block in run'
         # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:372:in `map'
         # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:372:in `run'
         # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:28:in `block (2 levels) in run'
         # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:28:in `map'
         # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:28:in `block in run'
         # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:34:in `report'
         # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:25:in `run'
         # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run'
         # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'
     Shared Example Group: "normal errors for html format" called from ./spec/controllers/application_controller_spec.rb:31
     # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-expectations-2.13.0/lib/rspec/expectations/fail_with.rb:32:in `fail_with'
     # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-expectations-2.13.0/lib/rspec/expectations/handler.rb:33:in `handle_matcher'
     # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-expectations-2.13.0/lib/rspec/expectations/expectation_target.rb:34:in `to'
     # ./spec/controllers/application_controller_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:114:in `instance_eval'
     # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:114:in `block in run'
     # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/extensions/instance_eval_with_args.rb:16:in `instance_exec'
     # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/extensions/instance_eval_with_args.rb:16:in `instance_eval_with_args'
     # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:247:in `instance_eval_with_args'
     # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:87:in `block (2 levels) in run'
     # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:89:in `call'
     # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:89:in `run'
     # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:418:in `run_hook'
     # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:329:in `run_around_each_hooks'
     # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:256:in `with_around_each_hooks'
     # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:111:in `run'
     # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:390:in `block in run_examples'
     # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:386:in `map'
     # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:386:in `run_examples'
     # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:371:in `run'
     # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:372:in `block in run'
     # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:372:in `map'
     # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:372:in `run'
     # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:372:in `block in run'
     # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:372:in `map'
     # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:372:in `run'
     # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:372:in `block in run'
     # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:372:in `map'
     # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:372:in `run'
     # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:372:in `block in run'
     # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:372:in `map'
     # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:372:in `run'
     # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:28:in `block (2 levels) in run'
     # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:28:in `map'
     # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:28:in `block in run'
     # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:34:in `report'
     # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:25:in `run'
     # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run'
     # /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'

Finished in 0.052 seconds
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/application_controller_spec.rb:5 # ApplicationController#handle_exceptions when runtime error happens with http format behaves like normal errors for html format raises the error

Randomized with seed 2493

Coverage report generated for RSpec to /home/fotanus/work/translation_proxy/coverage. 236 / 548 LOC (43.07%) covered.
```

I'm using Rails 3.2.13 and rspec 2.13.1

I haven't write Anonymou anywhere. See the following output:

```
grep -rin --exclude-dir=log --binary-files=text Anonymou .
./tmp/cache/assets/DE8/730/sprockets%2Fa51ac8eb9ee0a56c6c04ae1c21184baf:612:            // We use an anonymous function so that context is window
./tmp/cache/assets/DE8/730/sprockets%2Fa51ac8eb9ee0a56c6c04ae1c21184baf:9800:   // understands anonymous AMD modules. A named AMD is safest and most robust
./tmp/cache/assets/C8A/4B0/sprockets%2Ff16dfcb3e634f5416377592c25469801:612:            // We use an anonymous function so that context is window
./tmp/cache/assets/C8A/4B0/sprockets%2Ff16dfcb3e634f5416377592c25469801:9800:   // understands anonymous AMD modules. A named AMD is safest and most robust
./tmp/cache/assets/D78/320/sprockets%2F95003f96fcb4963ddf27265db635eabe:612:            // We use an anonymous function so that context is window
./tmp/cache/assets/D78/320/sprockets%2F95003f96fcb4963ddf27265db635eabe:9800:   // understands anonymous AMD modules. A named AMD is safest and most robust
./tmp/cache/assets/CD9/940/sprockets%2F1b1af54f9943c03a292c5d52227619dd:612:            // We use an anonymous function so that context is window
./tmp/cache/assets/CD9/940/sprockets%2F1b1af54f9943c03a292c5d52227619dd:9800:   // understands anonymous AMD modules. A named AMD is safest and most robust
./tmp/cache/assets/DDC/400/sprockets%2Fcffd775d018f68ce5dba1ee0d951a994:612:            // We use an anonymous function so that context is window
./tmp/cache/assets/DDC/400/sprockets%2Fcffd775d018f68ce5dba1ee0d951a994:9800:   // understands anonymous AMD modules. A named AMD is safest and most robust
./spec/spec_helper.rb:22:  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = true
./spec/controllers/application_controller_spec.rb:23:      get 'anonymous/runtime_error'
./spec/controllers/application_controller_spec.rb:24:      get 'anonymous/handable_json_error'
```

What is wrong?

Comment: You must have mistakenly wrote `Anonymou` instead of `Anonymous` somewhere. In your rails directory, do `grep -rin Anonymous app` and `grep -rin Anonymous spec` to find out where you wrote `Anonymou`

Comment: @JasonKim Edited the question with the grep output

Comment: What are in those sprocket processed files that match the pattern?

Comment: @Fred Update the question with a command to see what is anonymous inside. If my command is incorrect feel free to ask for any output.

Comment: Add --binary-files=text to your grep options, or use a text editor to look.

Comment: @Fred thanks for the grep flag. The output is the similar, but since it is more concise I updated the answer.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin that is crazy. Any tips of how to detect that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when an rspec anonymous controller calls CanCan's `load_and_authorize_resource` (probably because it's called by `ApplicationController`).

CanCan infers the name of the model from the name of the controller.  It infers `Anonymou` from `AnonymousController` due to the inflection issue mentioned by @AbeVoelker.

Call `skip_load_and_authorize_resource` to fix the error:

```rb
controller do
  skip_load_and_authorize_resource

  def index
    raise RuntimeError
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd guess Rails is confused when trying to inflect "anonymous" as it ends with an "s."  Add this to `config/initializers/inflections.rb`:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.singular('anonymous', 'anonymous')
end
```

From [the docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#inflections), you can check it in your Rails console:

```
"anonymous".singularize # => "anonymou"
# after adding above to inflections initializer
"anonymous".singularize # => "anonymous"
```

Comment: Nice one! But after this, the error is idiotic:  `expected RuntimeError, got #<NameError: uninitialized constant Anonymous`

Comment: Oops, guess I skimmed your question.  I had assumed you had an `Anonymous` model and relevant controller.  I'll let someone else answer as I've never used anonymous controllers with rspec before.

Comment: This was my first assumption too.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting this in your `spec_helper.rb`

```
config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = true
```

Beside, you cannot call other methods than REST one on anonymous controllers. See [here](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs/anonymous-controller) for more informations.

Try the following:

```
describe ApplicationController do
  controller do
    def index
      raise RuntimeError
    end

    def show
      raise ApplicationController::InvalidParams, "model"
    end
  end

  describe "#handle_exceptions" do
    context "when runtime error happens" do
      describe "with http format" do
        it_behaves_like "normal errors for html format", :index, RuntimeError
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I had this setting as false. Setting it to true changed nothing, for good or for bad. Thanks for try.

Comment: Alright, FYI more information here https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs/anonymous-controller

Comment: Edited my answer, maybe it will help :-/

Comment: Thanks, your code (with require rspec on the top) gives the same error (expected RuntimeError, got #<NameError: uninitialized constant Anonymou> with backtrace). I got the custom routes for anonymous controller in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027518/no-route-matches-rspecs-anonymous-controller)

Comment: The backtrace shows something with CanCan, can you show us your `spec_helper.rb` please ?

Comment: Add on the question. It is getting big :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35472/discussion-between-fotanus-and-pierre-louis-gottfrois)